# What will the quotas and pricing be when GAE (Google App Engine) Search API service comes out of experimental

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-search

It's really all but impossible for someone considering a migration to GAE to recommend going forward or even investigate this option if there is no information about the expected quotas or pricing for the Search API (for billing apps of course). These two variables are the first ones to consider when looking at the Search API. We know that there are missing features but, the basics are there.

By giving us some insights into this, you will surely get more people to investigate and try out GAE.

Answer (score 0):

You can find general availability Search quota information [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#search) and pricing information (for queries and data beyond the free tier) [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#search_pricing).